No sound in ASUS ROG Strix G712LV_G712LV with Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I've got a ASUS ROG Strix G712LV_G712LV with Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I've got sound using bluetooth or jack headphones but not with the internal speakers.
I've tried to add in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
options snd-hda-intel model=asus-zenbook

without effects.
Also I've edited the /usr/share/alsa-card-profile/mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common file and I've added
[Element Master]
switch = mute
volume = ignore

Are there any kind of final solution?
Thanks!
